# How do you remove the transit time from USPS shipping methods?

Tags: magento-1.9, usps

Shipping quote from USPS display something like:

> Priority Mail 1-Day $6.60

What's the proper way to change that so it only displays as "Priority Mail"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were having the same issue with USPS so we made a module that overrides the `_filterServiceName()` function. This allows us to get rid of any "number of days" type info, with the ability to change it per-store from the Admin, and no need to manually add each "translation" like the other answer suggests.

app/code/local/YourNamespace/Usps/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNamespace_Usps>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </YourNamespace_Usps>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <usa>
                <rewrite>
                    <shipping_carrier_usps>YourNamespace_Usps_Model_Usa_Shipping_Carrier_Usps</shipping_carrier_usps>
                </rewrite>
            </usa>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/YourNamespace/Usps/Model/Usa/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php

```
<?php
class YourNamespace_Usps_Model_Usa_Shipping_Carrier_Usps extends Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Usps {
    function _filterServiceName($name) {
        $name = parent::_filterServiceName($name);


        if( !Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/usps/show_number_of_days') )
            $name = preg_replace('/\s+?\d+-day/i', '', $name); // Trim out the number of days, and an optional leading space.

        return $name;
    }
}
```

app/code/local/YourNamespace/Usps/etc/system.xml

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <carriers>
            <groups>
                <usps>
                    <fields>
                        <show_number_of_days translate="label">
                            <label>Show Number of Days</label>
                            <comment>If set to "No", "Priority Mail 3-Day", "Priority Mail 2-Day" and "Priority Mail 4-Day" will all show up as "Priority Mail".</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>129</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </show_number_of_days>
                    </fields>
                </usps>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```

app/etc/modules/YourNamespace_Usps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNamespace_Usps>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </YourNamespace_Usps>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Config Section

[image: Config Section]

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: Can i get help about USPS Media mail -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/227667/57334

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in: [override USPS shipping method name](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37130/override-usps-shipping-method-name).

make a copy of app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Rate.php to app/code/community/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Rate.php

then 
replace

```
->setMethodTitle($rate->getMethodTitle())
```

with

```
->setMethodTitle(Mage::helper('shipping')->__($rate->getMethodTitle()))
```

And add appropriate translations into the Mage_Shipping.csv file.

H/T Amasty for the answer.

note that I couldn't get this to work in 1.6.2, but it works fine in 1.9.0.1